# PySpark timestampFormat

Tags: python, pyspark

I have csv file with date field. Here is one sample value from that field :- `2020-05-25 17:00:27`

I am using the following code. **For some reason the date field is still coming out as string.**

```
df = (spark.read
             .format("csv")
             .option("header","true")
             .option("inferSchema","true")
             .option("timestampFormat","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
             .load(file)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are getting a string. But you can cast the date field to timestamp after you read the `df`:

```
df = df.withColumn('date_field', col('date_field').cast("timestamp"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply the schema along with the file path.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType, StructType, StructField, StringType

schema = StructType([
StructField('col1', StringType(), True),
StructField('date_col', TimestampType(), True),
StructField('col3', StringType(), True)
])

df = (spark.read
             .format("csv")
             .option("header","true")
             .option("inferSchema","true")
             .load(file, schema=schema)
)
```